# Getting device list using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get a list of devices associated with my Microsoft account. When somebody uses his Microsoft account for logging in into his Windows account, he can see that in https://account.microsoft.com/devices/ appears a new device, from which he has logged in. So, I'd like to get this list using API. I've tried to send GET request to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devices as the Documentation says using my access token, but an empty list is returned although in https://account.microsoft.com/devices/ there are registered devices. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The `/devices` endpoint hasn't been released so it isn't available under `/v1.0`. It is only available under `/beta`.

You can find details on how to use `/devices` in the Beta [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-devices?view=graph-rest-beta&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0).

Comment: thanks, but here is another question. How can I get an access token for the device.read scope? I'm making a query as written in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code writing `scope = user.read+offline_access+openid+email+profile` in the body and the access token from the response gives me 401 Error when trying to request beta/me/devices. I tried to add `+device.read` to scope and the response was `The scope 'user.read offline_access openid device_read' does not exist.`

Comment: The scope is `Device.Read` not `Device_Read` (a `.`, not an `_`).

Comment: There was a mistake, a wrote Device.Read, error message was `The scope 'user.read offline_access openid device.read' does not exist`

Comment: I'm also getting an empty list of devices when using the Microsoft Graph Beta .NET Nuget package, despite multiple Windows and Android devices being registered in the test Microsoft account. Other requests (e.g. for DriveItems) are successful. I'm using `var devices = await App.GraphClient.Me.Devices.Request().GetAsync();` Would you have any advice @asukaev or @Marc LaFleur

Comment: @hlbmallo I didn't find any solution:(

Comment: I had this working about two years ago. Today I get the empty device list. Did anybody figure it out?